# SSH port forwarding using python

Tags: ssh, vpn, python, port-forwarding, tunneling

I have a VPS that serves as my VPN server, and I want to use this VPS as a VPN using forwarding for my laptop which uses windows as OS. Is it possible to do so without using software like PuTTY, Bitvise SSH client, etc.? For example, can I use Python code?

Comment: you could rewrite `ssh` in python, I'm sure python is a capable enough language to do so. By the way, what version of windows do you have? Windows 10 and 11 have openssh, I believe it comes as standard too

Comment: What purpose does the port forwarding have, are you providing some kind of service that needs to listen on these ports? What VPN technology have you selected for this Windows host?